# Mock return value of decorator on method under test

Tags: python, monkeypatching

As the title says, I'm having a little trouble trying to check that my function under test is decorated with the correct decorator for one, and secondly the right parameters.

***Method under test***

```
@command_wrapper.command('string1', 'string2')
def function_under_test():
    return some_other_function();
```

***Unit test***

```
@patch("command_wrapper.command")
def test_function_under_test(self, mock_command_wrapper)
    * Do some testing *
```

***Decorator: command_wrapper.py***

```
def command(string1, string2):
    cmd_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def func_wrapper():
            * Do some code *
    return func_wrapper
return cmd_decorator
```

However when the test runs, its clearly executing the decorator without having mocked it. I'm new to Python so I'm not even sure if this is possible, or whether this is the right approach.

Comment: decorators are run a single time when the function is defined (in this case at import time). You can patch before the import, but that would mean the function will permanently use the patched decorator in that function for the duration of the python process, which probably isn't what you want. Is there no way to test your function as is - with the original decorator?

Comment: @JosephIreland That could potentially be fine. Is there any way to unpatch the decorator in a tear down?

Comment: I dont think so. You can't unpatch it for the same reason you can't patch it.

Comment: @JosephIreland could you point me in the right direction for doing it at import time?

Comment: i actually found out you can make it work with the reload() function, added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators are run at module import time, so you need to patch it when it is being imported. You can do this by force reloading the module, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module), and again after its unpatched to revert it.

e.g.:

```
#python3.4+ only:
from importlib import reload
# python 3.X:
# from imp import reload
# python2 reload is built-in

import module_under_test

def test()
    try:
        with patch("command_wrapper.command") as mock_wrapper:
            # make decorator return function unchanged
            mock_wrapper.return_value.side_effect = lambda func: func
            reload(module_under_test)
            ** test stuff **
    finally:
        reload(module_under_test)
```

This is a bit hacky, probably better to find another way to test, but I think it will work.

Comment: Yup, this kinda works. We're now able to test the decorator has the right parameters passed to it. However, it now means that `mock_wrapper` doesn't return the method under test and doesn't execute it

Comment: added an example of how to make the replacement decorator do something useful

Comment: You also could do `from command_wrapper import command` at the top, and set `mock_wrapper.side_effect = command`. Then I think it would return the function with the original decorator after running the mock. Or you can replace the decorator with anything you want in a similar way